# Convert Pandas column with mixed (datetime, and integer) values to datetime only

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
in: 
df.date

out:
0 1987-06-24 00:00:00
1 19910922
```

I have a pandas column that is a mix of integer and DateTime types. I am trying to convert the integer values into datetime.

Usually the column is only integers, and I use `df.date= pd.to_datetime((df.date.astype(str)), format='%Y%m%d')`
 to convert the column into a datetime format.

How do I handle this when some datetime values are thrown into the column?

Comment: did you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920871/handling-pandas-dataframe-columns-with-mixed-date-formats)

Comment: Yes, couldnt find a way to use `errors`

Comment: Answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180685/changing-all-dates-to-standard-date-time-in-dataframe