# Pandas datetime validation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to check if the date time format in a certain column of a csv file is in the correct format.

I am using this:

```
if pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors ='raise'):
    print('date format wrong')
```

However dates if the format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S  still gets through.

Any advice out there? Thanks in advance!

Added by Scott Boston:

```
s = pd.Series(['2020-01-01 12:01:00','2020/01/01 12:02:00'])
pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='raise')
```

Output:

```
0   2020-01-01 12:01:00
1   2020-01-01 12:02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: _However dates if the format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S still gets through._ Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: 6/3/2020  2:30:19 PM, for example in my csv file does not throw any errors

Comment: That is not enough to form a [mcve], there are easily a million things in the program which could lead to this issue.

Comment: you have messed up your parentheses. Anyway, that does not seem like the right way to check for multiple date types. I would try something like this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920871/handling-pandas-dataframe-columns-with-mixed-date-formats  As AMC said, people could probably help you within minutes if you simply could create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Hrm.. interesting... That is unexpected, however, why wouldn't you want it to interpret both as dates?